# How can I add relation to my repository pattern with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

I have a repository pattern that I am using for an application. Everything is working perfectly today. However, I want to add ability to include relations to other models.

Here is my current `IRepository`

```
public interface IRepository<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{

    // Get records by it's primary key
    TModel Get(int id);

    // Get all records
    IEnumerable<TModel> GetAll();

    // Get all records matching a lambda expression
    IEnumerable<TModel> Find(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);

    // Get the a single matching record or null
    TModel SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate);

    // Add single record
    TModel Add(TModel entity);

    // Add multiple records
    IEnumerable<TModel> AddRange(IEnumerable<TModel> entities);

    // Remove records
    void Remove(TModel entity);

    // remove multiple records
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TModel> entities);
}
```

Here is my Entity implementation

```
public class EntityRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
where TEntity : class
{
protected readonly DbContext Context;

protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

public EntityRepository(DbContext context)
{
    Context = context;
    DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public TEntity Get(int id)
{
    return DbSet.Find(id);
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return DbSet.ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DbSet.Where(predicate);
}

public TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DbSet.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}

public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
{
    TEntity record = DbSet.Add(entity);

    return record;
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> records = DbSet.AddRange(entities);

    return records;
}

public void Remove(TEntity entity)
{
    DbSet.Remove(entity);
}

public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    DbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
}
```

Now, I want to add another method to allow me to handle lazy loading.
In another words, I want to be able to do something like this

```
using(var con = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var task = con.Tasks.With(x => x.Owner).GetAll();
}
```

Here in my Unit of work class

```
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private bool Disposed = false;
    private readonly ModuleContext Context;

    public ITaskRepository Tasks { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(ModuleContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        Tasks = new TaskRepository(Context);
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!Disposed && Context != null && disposing)
        {
            Context.Dispose();
        }

        Disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Here is my task model

```
public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Owner")]
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add a way to allow me to include relations to different models?

Comment: Dump the repository/unit of work stuff. See: https://cpratt.co/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/. TL;DR: Entity Framework *already* implements these patterns. Your `DbContext` is your unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository. All you're doing is adding another meaningless abstraction on top, that requires additional maintenance.

Comment: While it is true that the DbContext already implements these, we don't know the intents of the OP. It might be that they want to abstract away EF entirely so the DAL can later be based on some other technology (maybe EF core). In this case, it doesn't make a difference if the DbContext already implements these patterns. Also, mocking your DAL if you have a repository/unit of work layer can be easier for unit testing. In my experience, mocking the DbContext is a bit convoluted.

Comment: And what if I don't want to use EF later? And... If I dump the pattern as per your suggestion. Where would I save my reusable code? If I have a where clause that I use everywhere, where would I save that so I have one place for all my logic

Comment: @Junior It's an illusion that you're going to switch to another ORM seamlessly. See [this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/). If you want to hide ORM implementation details you're going to miss out on many of its specific features. Your question perfectly proves that. You accepted an answer that exposes the EF-specific `Include` method. But even without it, you always have to be aware of supported LINQ features, ways to save object graphs, well, too many EF idiosyncrasies to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an overload for your methods to the repository interface to accept a list of possible include-expressions. E.g.

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>[] includes)
{
   var query = DbSet;
   foreach (var include in includes)
   {
      query = query.Include(include);
   }
   return query.ToList();
 }
```

And then you can just write:

```
uow.Tasks.GetAll(t=>t.Owner);
```

For the filtered case you can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>> filter, params Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>[] includes)
{
   var query = DbSet;
   foreach (var include in includes)
   {
      query = query.Include(include);
   }
   return query.Where(filter).ToList();
 }
```

And then you can just write:

```
uow.Tasks.Find(t=>t.Something==2, t=>t.Owner);
```

Comment: Thank you. What about in the case I want to filter then include relations? .where().include()...

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, what is wrong with returning `IQueryable<TEntity>`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with returning `IQueryable<T>`. Actually I even prefer that approach, because that way I have more control over when the query executes and can even compose the query further, adding more filters or whatever, before executing it. I just used `IEnumerable<T>` in the examples, because that's what you had originally in yours as well.

Comment: should be `Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>[] includes`

Comment: @formicini Very true, thank you for spotting it

Comment: @AkosNagy you're welcome, and you missed a spot; the "filtered case" also has its brackets missing.